# ascii decoding error in an ascii file (Python 3.5)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a text  file (created by redirecting the output of `find` command in linux). The first 4 lines of the file are shown below :

```
/home/uujjwal/datasets/pedestrian/INRIAPerson/Train/pos/person_299.png
/home/uujjwal/datasets/pedestrian/INRIAPerson/Train/pos/crop001540.png
/home/uujjwal/datasets/pedestrian/INRIAPerson/Train/pos/crop001044.png
/home/uujjwal/datasets/pedestrian/INRIAPerson/Train/pos/person_195.png
```

I read it in Python 2.7 as a complete string by using the following :

```
fid = open('filelist.txt', 'r').read() # Successful
```

When I try to do the same in python 3.5, I get the following error :

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 141: invalid continuation byte
```

I realised the differences between python 3.5 and 2.7 and tried to specify the `ascii` encoding. I determined the `ascii` encoding by using the [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) package as follows (using its command line tool) :

```
 [uujjwal@rotanev pos]$ chardetect /home/uujjwal/datasets/pedestrian/INRIAPerson/Train/pos/filelist.txt
/home/uujjwal/datasets/pedestrian/INRIAPerson/Train/pos/filelist.txt: ascii with confidence 1.0
```

Hence I did the following :

```
fstr = open(annotation_file, 'r', encoding='ascii').read() #Failure
```

This gave the following error :

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 141: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I want to understand that :

1. Why these errors are popping up ?
2. What is wrong about my steps to resolve the problem.

**NOTE:** I did not manually modify the text file in any way.

**Addendum**

1. I checked the entire contents of the file. It has letters a-z, A-Z, 0-9 (All with well known ASCII values) forward slash (/) (**extended ASCII value of 47**) and underscore (_) (**extended  ASCII value of 95**) alongwith a dot (.) (**extended ASCII value of 46**). It also has newline character (** extended ASCII Value of 10**). There are no other characters in the file.
2. The byte 0xf4 corresponds to the extended ASCII of 244 (paragraph sign). This is something which just cannot exist as the file has been created by redirecting the output of `find` command.

Comment: Your file does not contain ASCII then. In Python 2, all you do is read bytes, no decoding is done.

Comment: Chardet can be wrong; it uses heuristics and is *not infallible*.

Comment: ASCII is only 0 to 127.

Comment: What does `with open('filelist.txt', 'rb') as f: print(f.read(150)[130:])` output? That gives us a context of 20 bytes around the decoding error.

Comment: @Ujjwal: consider upvoting the answer besides accepting it if not already done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is not ASCII encoded. Chardet uses heuristics and does not test the whole file, and got it wrong here. It isn't UTF-8 either, evidenced by the other error.

Chardet can't always tell what it is looking at:

```
>>> chardet.detect((('This mostly ASCII, with a hidden surprise' * 20) + 'hellø').encode('utf8'))
{'encoding': 'ISO-8859-2', 'confidence': 0.7225312698370376}
```

The `ø` encoded to just two bytes:

```
>>> 'ø'.encode('utf8')
b'\xc3\xb8'
```

which is not enough information for chardet to make the right call.

Use a different codec to open the file. What codec exactly is hard to say; in Latin-1 and Windows Codepage 1252, 0xF4 is the `ô` character, which doesn't immediately look like it'd fit in with the minimal data you've shown (position 141 would be within those first 4 lines).

Note that in Python 2, you really only read the binary contents of the file, without the data being decoded to Unicode text, which is why you don't get the error there.

Note that there is no such thing as 'extended ASCII'. The term [exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) but is bogus, there is no *standard* with that name, and is used for almost any 8-bit codec that is a superset of ASCII. A byte value 0xF4 means different things in different codecs; in the [IBM 775 codepage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_775) it is the [Paragraph (Pilcrow) symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow), as would it be in  code pages 850, 856, 857 and 858.